# Is using constraint/auto-layout on iPad a mandatory?

Tags: ios, ipad, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

All iPad screens, **iPad 1, iPad 2 ... , iPad Retina and Mini iPad** have the same screen ratio. `width/height` or `height/width` or `width:height`

> So, Why do we need to use constraints for the iPad views?!

I also believe that in interface builder when you select the view controller, you can view it as iPad or iPhone. there is many iPhone options but only one iPad option. you can do that by clicking the size drop down list in the `Attributes Inspector`.

Is there any of the iPad screens that have more or less screen points comparing to others? "Screen Points" not "Screen Pixels" if yes, Which one is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use auto layout, but it's a good idea to. Once you understand it it's faster to work with, more flexible and very powerful for animations. You should also consider device rotation and usage for things like multi-tasking (ios9, use size classes too).

Comment: Thank you. Ya I understand it. but, some times the view is complicated and adding the constraints takes time. and I do animations a lot. but, I use uiview animation. and I have to re-correct the frames for my animated views in viewdidlayoutsubviews method. how you do animation with constraint. Is it by setting the constraint constant in the animation block?

Comment: Is your firm looking for an iOS developer? :)

Comment: Exactly, just set the constraint constant and request a layout in the animation block. And yes, but all roles are London UK based so you might have quite a commute ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you Design your Screens in Width Any / height any than your design will run on any iphone and Ipad Screen with autolayout. And it's a good practice too. if you want any change for iphone / ipad screen than you can remove that constraint for particular devices.add particluar constraint for particular devices.